# PatternSyntaxException when using String.match()

Tags: java, regex

The following seemingly innocuous pattern is causing a PatternSyntaxException:

```
String pattern = "^(?:.*)\\s*{$"; // pattern is:   ^(?:.*)\s*{$
```

As you can see when you look at it in [regexpal](http://regexpal.com), it seems to work properly there.

For example, that string should match:

```
name {
```

The message I'm getting back is "Illegal repetition near index 9", but I have no idea what I'm doing that's illegal.  The offending character is supposed to match any number of whitespace characters between the final section and the {.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `{` with `\\`.

Comment: I can't accept an answer yet for some reason but this has fixed it.

Comment: @Wug.. You would be able to do it after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `opening curly brace` with two backslashes.

```
String pattern = "^(?:.*)\\s*\\{$"
```